# How do you retrieve a Virustotal file scan report using the VT::API cpan module?

Tags: perl, cpan

I installed the `VT::API` cpan module that purports to make sending files and receiving reports using the Virustotal public API easy. Unfortunately the documentation is very general and I could not find even one simple example on how to use it. So far I have:

```pl
use VT::API;

$num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args != 1) {
  print "\nNo file specified\n\n";
  exit;
}

$file_name=$ARGV[0];

# OO-interface.
my $api = VT::API->new(key => '<===== my API key =====>');

# Send and scan a file.
my $res2 = $api->scan_file("$file_name");
```

This works without error but I tried printing `$res2` and get blank output.

I tried:

```pl
# Retrieve a file scan report.
# If query successfull hash reference returned.
# my $res1 = $api->get_file_report('md5/sha1/sha256 or permalink identifier');
my $res1 = $api->get_file_report($res2);
```

but get `You have not specified a resource (md5/sha1/sha256 or permalink identifier)`.

So I guess my question is, how do you get the `md5/sha1/sha256 or permalink identifier` of the submitted file and what form does `$res1` take? I need to be able to display the results.

Answer (score 0):

use a module like [Crypt::Digest::SHA256](http://search.cpan.org/~mik/CryptX-0.021/lib/Crypt/Digest/SHA256.pm) to calc the sha256 of your file, and use that hash in the get_file_report call

Comment: OK I tried that:

`use Crypt::Digest::SHA256 qw( sha256_file );    $file_name=$ARGV[0];    $sha256_raw = sha256_file("$file_name");    print "\n$sha256_raw\n";`

And I get:

`???34??{L?K*u?G8T?M??J?????7`

That doesn't look like any sha256 I've ever seen. In any case, `my $res1 = $api->get_file_report($sha256_raw);` still yields blank result.

Comment: Of course part of the problem is a long delay in getting the file scanned: `files sent using the API have the lowest scanning priority, depending on VirusTotal's load, it may take several hours before the file is scanned, so query the report at regular intervals until the result shows up and do not keep sending the file once and over again`

Comment: use the sha256_file_hex function

Comment: OK, that's better. I get `9ca0c93334a0967b4cd54b2a75aa47013854ee4df4e14ad702fbafa68b063719
`. But that still doesn't help get the report.

Answer (score 0):

VT::API works, but there does seem to be a one problem with the documentation.

I'll begin by saying that I don't know why `$res` should print as blank for you.

It should be a hash.

One of the keys of the hash is 'report'. This probably contains what you want.

The value of 'report' is an array, containing another hash, containing any matches returned.

If your file scans clean, the hash will be pretty boring, just a list of AV vendors.

Sometimes you need to wait a while to get results - use `get_file_report()` for this, don't keep resubmitting the same file.

If your file generates hits, then the hash will be more interesting.

For example, scanning [EICAR](http://www.eicar.org/85-0-Download.html) returns something like this:

```pl
'result' => 1,
'permalink' => 'https://www.virustotal.com/file/275a021bbfb6489e54d471899f7db9d1663fc695ec2fe2a2c4538aabf651fd0f/analysis/',
'report' => [
  '2018-03-27 19:14:15',
  {
    'Kaspersky' => 'EICAR-Test-File',
    'F-Prot' => 'EICAR_Test_File',
    'Fortinet' => 'EICAR_TEST_FILE',
    'Arcabit' => 'EICAR-Test-File (not a virus)',
    ...
```

If you can't test with EICAR because, for example, your AV eats it, you can upload a hash of the EICAR file.

For example: `my $res = $api->get_file_report('3395856ce81f2b7382dee72602f798b642f14140');`

PS. For anyone new to the party, to get a VirusTotal API key:

1. register for an account at https://www.virustotal.com
2. navigate to user-image->settings->api key (or go straight to https://www.virustotal.com/#/settings/apikey)